# Vagrant - Default synced folder not available

Tags: vagrant

I have a Vagrant file like this

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.box_check_update = false
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "8192"
    vb.cpus = "2"
  end
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "install.sh"
end
```

Th final script called is :
`cp /conf/pgsql/pg_hba.conf /home/vagrant/pg_hba.conf`

Arborescence is ok :

[image]

When i launch `vagrant up --provision` i can see that my file is not copied, the synced folder "/vagrant/conf" seems to be unavailable

[image]

I'm using last version of Vagrant, on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

"Hard" solution :

- Uninstall Vagrant
- Remove all folders ".vagrant.d" and "VirtualBox" in "C:\Users\MyUser"
- Download latest version of Vagrant
- `vagrant up`
- `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`
- `vagrant reload`

Done.